# I am unable to change a column into Date format in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

[image: This is how my data looks]

And this is the string of my dataframe.

```
'data.frame':   10652 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date: chr  "06-15-2017" "06-15-2017" "06-15-2017" "06-15-2017" ...
 $ Time: Factor w/ 951 levels "00:00:01","00:00:02",..: 396 398 400 402 404 406 407 409 411 413 ...
 $ CPU : num  2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3 2.2 2.2 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 ...
 $ MEM : num  2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.7 2.9 2.9 ...
```

I want to make R read the date and time column in Date and Time format.

I have tried:

1. `DateData$Date_Time = within(DateData, { timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(DateData$Date, DateData$Time)), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") })`
2. I have tried this after merging the date and time column-
   `DateData$Date_Time = as.chron(DateData$Date_Time, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`
3. `DateData = within(DateData, { timestamp=strptime(paste((DateData$Date, DateData$Time), "%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S") })`
4. And this: `DateData$DateTime = strptime(DateData$DateTime,"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Use `DateData$Date_Time = as.Date(DateData$Date_Time, "%m-%d-%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dealing with conversion after importing data

This is a sample of your data

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = c("06-15-2017","06-15-2017","06-15-2017","06-15-2017"), Time = c("00:00:01", "00:00:02", "00:00:03", "00:00:04"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

For date object, you can use either base R, `lubridate` or `anytime`
packages

```r
df$Date_base <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%m-%d-%y")

library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
df$Date_lubridate <- mdy(df$Date)

library(anytime)
df$Date_anytime <- anytime(df$Date)
```

For working with time objects only (not Datetime), you can work with
`hms` package or `period` objects form lubridate package with
`lubridate::hms`

```r
library(hms)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'hms'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     hms
df$Time_hms <- as.hms(df$Time)
df$Time_lubridate <- lubridate::hms(df$Time) # hms in lubridate is masked by hms package
```

here are what results look like

```r
df
#>         Date     Time  Date_base Date_lubridate Date_anytime Time_hms
#> 1 06-15-2017 00:00:01 2020-06-15     2017-06-15   2017-06-15 00:00:01
#> 2 06-15-2017 00:00:02 2020-06-15     2017-06-15   2017-06-15 00:00:02
#> 3 06-15-2017 00:00:03 2020-06-15     2017-06-15   2017-06-15 00:00:03
#> 4 06-15-2017 00:00:04 2020-06-15     2017-06-15   2017-06-15 00:00:04
#>   Time_lubridate
#> 1             1S
#> 2             2S
#> 3             3S
#> 4             4S
```

Class of the column and summary of df

```r
sapply(df, class)
#> $Date
#> [1] "character"
#> 
#> $Time
#> [1] "character"
#> 
#> $Date_base
#> [1] "Date"
#> 
#> $Date_lubridate
#> [1] "Date"
#> 
#> $Date_anytime
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
#> 
#> $Time_hms
#> [1] "hms"      "difftime"
#> 
#> $Time_lubridate
#> [1] "Period"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "lubridate"
summary(df)
#>      Date               Time             Date_base         
#>  Length:4           Length:4           Min.   :2020-06-15  
#>  Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:2020-06-15  
#>  Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :2020-06-15  
#>                                        Mean   :2020-06-15  
#>                                        3rd Qu.:2020-06-15  
#>                                        Max.   :2020-06-15  
#>  Date_lubridate        Date_anytime          Time_hms       
#>  Min.   :2017-06-15   Min.   :2017-06-15   Length:4         
#>  1st Qu.:2017-06-15   1st Qu.:2017-06-15   Class1:hms       
#>  Median :2017-06-15   Median :2017-06-15   Class2:difftime  
#>  Mean   :2017-06-15   Mean   :2017-06-15   Mode  :numeric   
#>  3rd Qu.:2017-06-15   3rd Qu.:2017-06-15                    
#>  Max.   :2017-06-15   Max.   :2017-06-15                    
#>  Time_lubridate 
#>  Min.   :1S     
#>  1st Qu.:1.75S  
#>  Median :2.5S   
#>  Mean   :2.5S   
#>  3rd Qu.:3.25S  
#>  Max.   :4S
```

## Dealing with conversion directly when reading

You can deal with type conversion directly when you read a file from a file using the `readr` package.

```r
library(readr)
read_csv('Date, Time
06-15-2017, 00:00:01
06-15-2017, 00:00:02
06-15-2017, 00:00:03
06-15-2017, 00:00:04
', col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%m-%d-%Y"), 
                    Time = col_time()))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>         Date     Time
#>       <date>   <time>
#> 1 2017-06-15 00:00:01
#> 2 2017-06-15 00:00:02
#> 3 2017-06-15 00:00:03
#> 4 2017-06-15 00:00:04
```

Using `readr`, you see that it directly import your data in a data.frame (a special `tibble` format from `tidyverse`) with column as Date and Time. You can find some information [here](http://readr.tidyverse.org/articles/readr.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me. I also wanted to have a date and time together and which can be read is date-time format by R. Is this possible?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to import with column as character, then use `lubridate::mdy_hms(paste(df$Date, df$Time, sep = " "))` to create a new datetime column

Comment: However, you can also import your Date column as a Datetime object with time part as 00:00:00. Then you create a new column adding Date column + Time column. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You used date-time formats that don't match your data at multiple places.
If you paste the `Date` and `Time` columns together with a space separator, the format to parse is `%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S`.

That is, to combine the two columns and parse as date-time:

```
DateData$DateTime <- strptime(paste(DateData$Date, DateData$Time, sep=' '), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

## installing lubridate package

install.packages("lubridate")
library (lubridate)

## pasting the Date and Time Column

DFanalysis$DateStamp <- paste(DFanalysis$Date, DFanalysis$Time, sep = " ")

## Check the class of DateStamp

class(DFanalysis$DateStamp)

## If the class is character we can convert it directly

DFanalysis$DateStamp <- mdy_hms(DFanalysis$DateStamp)